# Laravel response download problem return characters instead of file

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Download function on my controller working well on local but when I tried it on Heroku, it returns like this instead of file like this (I will not display the whole text)

> %PDF-1.2
> %ùúšç 25 0 obj << /E 87146 /H [1654 181] /L 211642 /Linearized 1 /N 4
> /O 28 /T 211093
> xref 25 15 0000000017 00000 n 0000001236 00000 n 0000001654 00000 n
> 0000001835 00000 n 0000002188 00000 n 0000002291 00000 n 0000002399
> 00000 n 0000002514 00000 n 0000002695 00000 n 0000003180 00000 n
> 0000004432 00000 n 0000004776 00000 n

Here's my code:

```
public function downloadArticle(Request $req){
    $d = '';
    if(gettype($req->path) == 'array'){
        $d = "/app/public/".$req->refNo."/articleFiles/".$req->path[0]['path'];
        // \dd($d,"/public/".$req->refNo."/articleFiles/".$req->path[0]['path']);

    }
    else{
        $d = "/app/".$req->path;
    }
    return response()->download(\storage_path().$d);
}
```

Anyone encountered the same prob?

Comment: What you get with `return file_get_contents(storage_path('\storage_path()' . $d));`?

Comment: `return file_get_contents(storage_path('\storage_path()' . $d));` when i tried this line it returns text like on the aforementioned both local and heroku.

Comment: And what you get with `return response(storage_path().$d, 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', File::mimeType(storage_path().$d));`?

Comment: It only returns the path @porloscerrosΨ